# When the window is maximized, it has an offset

Tags: c#, wpf

[image: screenshot]

The red line is the desktop, and the window position has an 7px offset to the left, and a 7px offset to the top. How can I move the window right by 7px and down by 7px?

I have this in XAML to set the window's max width and height:

```
    MaxWidth = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Width}"
    MaxHeight = "{Binding Source={x:Static SystemParameters.WorkArea}, Path=Height}"
```

EDIT:

```
    private void BTN_Maximize_MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsMaximized)
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        }
        else
        {
            WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        }
    }
    bool IsMaximized
    {
        get
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you show how you are maximizing?

Comment: @Alander Look at Edit.

Comment: so when it is maximized, you set to normal and vice versa? is that your intention?

Comment: @Alander Yeah, but the window is with 7 px in left.

Comment: Just don't set MaxWidth and MaxHeight.

Comment: A maximized window normally has the upper left corner of its frame at (-8, -8) so the border is not visible.  You are doing something screwy with the border, without either WPF or the OS knowing about it.  And without us knowing about it.  Handle the WM_GETMINMAXINFO message to do it your way.